# Error Throw when Table Creation

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, create-table

In my application I create a SQL Server Compact table via vb.net using this code:

```
 Dim connStringCS As String = "Data Source= Test.sdf; LCID= 1033; 
 Case Sensitive=true"

 Dim xconn As New SqlCeConnection(connStringCS)
 xconn.Open()
 Dim xcmd As New SqlCeCommand()
 xcmd.Connection = xconn
 xcmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE datalog(schema_oid binary NOT
 NULL,tablename ntext NOT NULL, " _
 & " refno nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, lastupdated datetime NOT NULL,
 status nvarchar(1) NOT NULL , " _
 & " PRIMARY KEY (schema_oid,tablename,refno)) "

 xcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I get an error

> Long value data type cannot be indexed

What am I doing wrong here?

How to solve this?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're using the `tablename ntext` in your primary key - **don't do this**! Don't put such a **long** column into a primary key! Use an `INT` or a `BIGINT` or something - not a combination of three columns, with a `ntext` in the middle of it.... How to solve it? Just **don't put** `ntext` columns in indexes - as the error really clearly says ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're using the `tablename ntext` column in your primary key - **don't do this**! Don't put such a long column into a primary key! That's really bad idea.

Use an `INT` or a `BIGINT` or something like that - not a combination of three columns, with a `ntext` in the middle of it....

*How to solve it?* Just don't put `ntext` columns in indexes - as the error really clearly says ...